# Azure API Management Reverse Proxy for Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have a created a simple Azure Logic App that sends a file via FTP to a customer. I have tested the Logic App and it works to my VM. I have an issue however that my customer whitelists IP addresses that FTP to them and Azure will only supply you with regional IP addresses meaning anyone who uses Logic App in my region will have access to my customer. I have done some reading and it seems that the recommended way to do this is by using API Management as a Reverse Proxy.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2017/05/19/whitelisting-and-logic-apps/

Can someone explain how to do this? It seems you ftp to your API Management Gateway and it then forwards the request to customer. Its the forwarding bit i don't understand how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Azure API management only supports HTTP, so it would not be possible to use it as an FTP proxy. Perhaps you could host some secure endpoint in your VM and invoke it with Logic App, using your VM as a proxy. Surely more elaborate way.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Logic App is a Serverless PaaS offering, meaning you would not be able to obtain a Static IP just for your Logic App. Unless you are okay to setup an Integration Service Enrionment (ISE) to do - read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-set-up-single-ip-address).

However, please note that ISE is dedicated environment more like a piece of Azure assigned just for you to run your Logic Apps & doesn't come as part of the typical Logic App's Consumption based plan. This means higher pricing/cost.